# Flip background using CSS or LESS

Tags: html, css, less

Is there a way to programmatically flip the background of an element using CSS or LESS? Specifically, I would like to invert the background gradient of a button. I do not want the content of the button to be flipped - just the background.

For example, this:

```
.button {background-image:linear-gradient(top, #000, #fff);}
```

should become:

```
.button:active {background-image:linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000);}
```

-----------  EDIT: Adding more detail. -----------

Take this LESS code:

```
.button {

  background-image:linear-gradient(top, red, green);

  &.primary {background-image:linear-gradient(top, blue, yellow);}
  &.secondary {background-image:linear-gradient(top, brown, grey);}

  &:active {background-image:linear-gradient(top, ..., ...);}

}
```

Is there a way for me to reverse the direction of the gradient without having to define the ":active" state separately for the ".button", ".primary" and ".secondary" classes?

Comment: you don't mean background-image, right? you mean background-color

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: No, [he means background-image](http://css3please.com#box_gradient).

Comment: na, @Dr.Dredel - image works with gradients.

Comment: I guess you could use CSS `transform` to actually flip the element, but that seems like overkill for this question.

Comment: that would end up flipping the content of the button too, which i don't want.

Comment: Is adding a 3rd parameter for stating "reversed/not reversed" OK (along with beginning and ending colors to a gradient function)? Which LESS are you using exactly: LESS.js, lessphp, WP-LESS?

Answer (score 2):

### With Newer Browsers

This post is over a year old, but I thought I would note there is a solution now for some of the newer browsers. The following has been tested in IE10 (does not work in IE9 and under), FF21, and Chrome27.

Using a pseudo element and a transform, you can get what you originally desired. Originally, some issues did not allow transforms on pseudo elements, so this will not function in some older versions.

**[Here is the example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qV5sD/9/)** Though for fallback support, you [may still want the additional vendor prefixes](http://jsfiddle.net/qV5sD/8/).

**LESS**

```
.button {

  background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green);
  position: relative;

  &:after {
     content: '';  
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: -1;

     &:active {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
           -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
               transform: rotate(180deg);
     }
  }

  &.primary {background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, yellow);}
  &.secondary {background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, brown, grey);}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your `background-image:linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000);` css rule but if you want to change button's background I guess this is the way - instead of `.class` selector use `[type='']` otherwise `:active` wont work:

```
input[type="button"] {background:#fff;}
input[type="button"]:active {background:#000}
[...]
<input type="button" value="Test"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I don't think you understood my questions. I know how to change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UgQvg/2

?

Comment: visually, that's the final result I want but technically I don't want to explicitly define the colors to be flipped. I want it to be flipped another way so it can be applied globally for all buttons, for example.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean you don't want to define the colors to be flipped? You want to insert the colors dynamically as a separate class variable? I'm sure you can do that with LESS using the exact same methodology, but using a variable for the color, rather than an explicit value.

Comment: I'll update my question with more detail. I realize I am asking for something off the wall.

Comment: Updated with more detail. Hopefully it clarifies what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think LESS can work that way. You're basically trying to reference the colors of a nested scope using an outside scope - or rather, trying to get a polymorphism-like behavior. LESS just doesn't do that. It's cumbersome, but you'll probably have to define the `:active` portion for each button type. See [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ASuAR/3/).

Now, I think you *can* do something like this using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (like LESS, but server-side, Ruby-based), perhaps using a list variable containing the specialized button classes, and then an `@each` loop to generate the `:active` styles. But that's probably overkill, unless you have  a ***lot*** of specialized styles.

Nonetheless, if you're using LESS, you might want to take a look at [LESS Elements](http://lesselements.com/) - a useful set of mixins, which includes gradient support.

Comment: that works except I have several buttons (primary, secondary for e.g.) with different colors. I want to be able to use one rule to flip the colors of them all. So using the explicit variables is not going to work - or else i will have to define ".inverted" for all of them. Why one rule? I have al my buttons nested under a master ".button" definition in my less file.